# Maximum default POST request size of IIS 7 - how to increase 64kB/65kB limit?

Tags: asp.net, http, rest, iis, post

I have created a RESTful POST web service in ASp .net C# with IIS hosting the service.

My service accepts an XML file as input and when the size exceeds 65KB I get the following error message:

**The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**

my question is two fold, first is there a default limit set by the IIS server for POST requests and secondly how can I update this?

Many Thanks

Comment: I'm not going to vote Off-Topic because, when dealing with web-services on IIS, a dev (who otherwise doesn't care about server admin) might run into this issue, especially on a locally-configured environment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

John Källén's answer was correct, but in my case I had an end point defined so setting the maxReceivedMessageSize had to be as follows:

```
<standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" 
                         helpEnabled="true" 
                         automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"                   
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        </standardEndpoint>
    </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Comment: just wanted to make your rep more than 100 hehe

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried adding the following to your web.config?

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
<system.webServer>
```

This will bump up your allowed content length to a megabyte. Also, you may want to set the maxReceivedMessageSize attribute of your WCF bindings to more than the default 64k:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MessageSizeWeb" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
</webHttpBinding>
```

Comment: WCF web services also have limitations on request sizes. I'm trying to hunt that down for you.

Comment: @DafaDil: try adding the following attribute: <binding name="MyService.MyServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304">

Comment: Thanks for the help, Do i need to nest it using a <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>? or directly add it?

Comment: Inside your <webHttpBinding> there will be a <binding> element, add the maxReceivedMessageSize attribute there.

Comment: I presume that MyService should be set to the service name I have published?

Comment: Yes. I'm blindly copying from a WCF service I had on my machine that I was using to learn how to get past exactly this issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25106/discussion-between-dafadil-and-john-kallen)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25108/discussion-between-dafadil-and-john-kallen)