# 2D javascript array to c# datatable?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, arrays, json

I have a 2D javascript array that is filled with user data and checked for valid data.

How do I go about getting that 2D array passed to my c# code behind page?
I am going to use the c# code to push it to a database after further processing.

From searching it seems like I need to get it to some sort of json to pass it to the c# code, but i'm at a complete loss on how to do that exactly and then what to do once I get it to the c# code.

Javascript array looks like this

```
[["Q458","","100","85"],
["Q459","TS","90","65"],
["Q460","","80","15"]]
```

Comment: this is not a 2D? 2D array looks like this var x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

Comment: My formatting just isn't all there. I have fixed it.

Comment: have you tried to pass this to a hidden field as string and consume it in the code behind

Comment: That is what i'm trying to do but i'm not sure on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to achieve this with the `Newtonsoft.Json` library (available for download via NuGet Package Manager - in Visual Studio click Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for this solution and search for "Json").

First you send this array to your code-behind - probably via AJAX request supplying your array as a parameter. To create a JSON string out of your array object, use the JSON-js (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library's `stringify` function as follows:

```
var jsonArrayString = JSON.stringify( your_array );
```

This string you will now send to your server and use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize to an two dimensional list or array:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>( yourJsonString );
or
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[,]>(yourJsonString );
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on MZetko's answer, here's a method you can use with jQuery and Json.Net.

First, you'll need to set up a way to send the js array to your c# code. You can use something like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>

        var items = [["Q458", "", "100", "85"], ["Q459", "TS", "90", "65"], ["Q460", "", "80", "15"]];
        sendToDb(items);

        function sendToDb(inArr) {
            var inString = JSON.stringify(inArr);

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Handlers/some-generic-handler.ashx",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                data: { myVar: inString },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success == true) {
                        alert("Here's the first element in the array: " + data.firstElement)
                        alert(data.message);
                    }

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
 </script>
```

Now, you'll need to build a handler that will answer the ajax request. This page will use Json.Net. The code will look something like this:

```
public class some_generic_handler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string myVar = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["myVar"])) { myVar = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["myVar"].Trim(); }

        var myArr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(myVar);

        string firstElement = myArr[0][0];

        string response = String.Format(@"{{ ""success"" : true, ""message"" : ""Cool! We're done."", ""firstElement"" : ""{0}"" }}", firstElement);

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(response);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to install Json.Net by PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json, and then include the following reference:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

This demo will convert the js array to a string, send it to your handler page, the handler page will deserialize that string to a c# array, send back the first element in the array to the initial page, and then the initial page will alert the first element. In your application, you would use the handler page to insert data into your db table.

Comment: I have this somewhat working not this exact thing above but is there a limit to the amount of data sent across with the json message? When I test with only a few records in the array it works but when I try my production case with over 1k records it doesn't work. Should there be a config change I need to make or something like that?

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? Troubleshooting these ajax errors can be a pain sometimes. I normally go about it this way: run the page in Chrome, right click --> inspect element, click the "Network" tab, refresh the page, then you'll be able to see the page some-generic-handler.ashx (or whatever you named it)...right click --> open link in new tab. Is there an error? If there's no error, is your json valid (http://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: Also, it looks like the max POST size depends on your framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079397/maximum-default-post-request-size-of-iis-7-how-to-increase-64kb-65kb-limit

Comment: Yea it was the <httpRuntime maxRequestLength=""/> value needed to be increased. It is now accepting all my data. I used fiddler right after I posted and figured it out from the error it was giving me.

Comment: Sweet! I'm glad you got it working. I make these ajax calls all over the place. Even if you don't end up using this solution, hopefully it will help you out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass this from the client side to the server side using `asp:HiddenField`

**Client**

```
 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="myhf" Value="[['Q458','','100','85'],
                           ['Q459','TS','90','65'],['Q460','','80','15']]"/>
```

**Server**

```
    var ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var strArray = ser.Deserialize<string[][]>(myhf.Value);
```

now `strArray` is a 2D array you can loop through it and do you database insertion.