# Ajax call, error on receive JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I'm developing a ASP.net application. I send data from client to server by Ajax call(jQuery). The server receive all calls by methods with attribute [WebMethods] (Note: my application is hosted in SharePoint 2010 Foundation).

When I receive a lot of data from server, Ajax call don't work.

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks

[EDIT - Added sample code and other]

Excuse for my tardiness response(I'm very committed to work). I execute my Ajax call like that code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../_layouts/MyApplication/MasterPage.aspx/GetMyData?nameParameter="+value,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
        cache: false,
        success: function (result)
        {
           //More code
        }
      });}
```

Server-side code is like that:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetMyData()
    {
        // Variables
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        // Connection
        try
        {
            // Getting data from database
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error GetMyData: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            objSqlConnection.Close();
        }

        // Serializer and return
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = serializer.Serialize(rows);
        return json;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to answer this question without code/print screens/error messages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem setting by code size limit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible request size exceeds the limit set in IIS. You can see similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079397/maximum-default-post-request-size-of-iis-7-how-to-increase-64kb-65kb-limit)