# I got error 500 when I try to post a json to webservice

Tags: c#, json, winforms, web-services

I'm developing an application in c# windows form , When I try to send a large json,  I got an exception erro 500.

[image]

This the method to POST

```
public void POST(string url, string jsonContent)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";

    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(jsonContent);

    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";


    using(Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
    long length = 0;
    try
    {
        using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
        {
            length = response.ContentLength;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {

        // Log exception and throw as for GET example above
    }
}
```

I can send others object in JSON, but especially this object that has a large datas I get this exception . 
But when I try to GET from webservice this same object it worked very well.

The problem is , I can get this large data but I can't send this same data.

Following the code of my controller.

```
[Route("reconhecimento")]
[HttpPost]
    public bool PostPessoasReconhecimento([FromBody]PessoaReconhecimentoModel[] newpessoaReconhecimento)
    {

    PessoaReconhecimentoModel pessoaReconhecimento = new PessoaReconhecimentoModel();
        return pessoaReconhecimento.postPessoaReconhecimento(newpessoaReconhecimento);
    }
```

Comment: Have you cliked `View detail...`? The webservice may have a limitation on how big POST data can be. PHP for instance has a default limit of 8Mb.

Comment: I did , I use c# , how can I fix it?  do you know ?

Comment: @Joab if you naivgate to the base object of your web exception you could get more detail (the instance of webexception you get).
In particular as Kenney suggested you can see if the problem is limitation of income message.
Let me know if it is the case and if you using selfhost or iis as server (i explain how to fix error)

Comment: I use iis as  server, I think the problem is because i send a large data

Answer (score 0):

Joab i suppose the problem could be related to dimension of your request.

Try to check if your question could be classified as duplicate of that ones :
[Maximum default POST request size of IIS 7 - how to increase 64kB/65kB limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079397/maximum-default-post-request-size-of-iis-7-how-to-increase-64kb-65kb-limit)

Comment: But, how could it be possible I get the same amount of data from web service and then I can't send the same data back ? , So this link it's about error 400, but my is 500

Comment: Joab data send and received is asimetric, the limit on income data is by less than default limit of send.
You are right about the fact that expected error should be 400 and not 500.
Usually 500 mean that there are applicative error, anyway i suggest to give try with new configuration and see if solve the error
Ps : if it does not solve the issue may be it's an applicative error on IIS, can you provide server code ?

Comment: I can,  but which part you want ?  web config , controllers etc... ?

Comment: the controller that handle the json you send back

Comment: ok, If I try to send data using fiddler for example I get success but If I try to use my application I got exception

Comment: @Joab have you found any solution?