# Send base64 image string using Ajax to a .NET WebService - I get a different string

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, web-services

I am trying to submit a base64 image string to a .NET webservice. I tried in two approaches:

1) Getting the string from a preview image src attribute

2) Getting the string  from within a DIV that I insert the base64 string into

note: When the string is in the preview src image, I can see the image, so the string stored there is fine.

I tried transfering it to the WebService with and without encodeURIComponent.

```
var formData = {
        screenshot: $(".uploadimage").attr("src")   
    };
```

or

```
var formData = {
       screenshot:$("#base64imagepreview").html()
}
```

I stringify the data before using the ajax request to the web service:

```
data: JSON.stringify(formData),
```

My problem is that the string of the base64 image is always different then the one the web service gets.

How can I transfer the string so it would be the same and it won't fail my `base64ToImage` function.

Here's part of the string that is changed:

```
P2Kxgxby0yA3NeQqxtuEjQEO7HcuDsD8qNl
```

Changes to this (this is just a part of the chance, the converted string continues):

```
P2...LWG1AUyHSvfONznr/
```

Something is changing and I have no idea why. **The string breaks after P2**.

It might be due to a maximum attribute length for the string (maxRequestLength) but I am not sure.

The original string is **56,331 bytes**. The one that the webservice consumed is **32,768 bytes**. Due to the three dots, I assume that .NET trims the string.

I am using regular webservice, not WCF.

Update: It tried to increase the `maxRequestLength` but it didn't solve the probolem.

Comment: might give you a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079397/maximum-default-post-request-size-of-iis-7-how-to-increase-64kb-65kb-limit

Comment: @Dekel Hi, I increased the maxAllowedContentLength to 100MB (104857600 bytes) and and the string still trims to 32,768 bytes

Comment: Did you also check the value of `maxReceivedMessageSize`?

Comment: @Dekel that's for WCF, I am not using WCF

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with that. Did you try to use fiddler to check if the browser actually post all the data? Try to check if the problem is in the browser or the server.

Comment: @Dekel Browser sent 59,405 bytes. Tested in Chrome, checked the header. So it's not a browser issue.