# Not able to send a soap request which is greater than 64KB to the WCF Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, jmeter

I have an MVC 5 Web Application, inside which I have a WCF Service with the following contract:

```
[ServiceContract(ConfigurationName="IDocumentGenerator")]
public interface IDocumentGenerator
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "GenerateDocument"), XmlSerializerFormat]
    Stream GenerateDocument(string DocId, string Format, string returnAs, string userName, string password, XmlDocument Payload);
}
```

I am using the following configuration inside the Web.Config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>    
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:64172/DocumentGenerator.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IDocumentGenerator" name="WebHttpBinding_IDocumentGenerator" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Next, I am using Apache JMeter to send a `Soap-XML/RPC Request` to the URL `http://localhost:64172/DocumentGenerator.svc` and all requests that are less than 65KB hit the IIS Express Server, but as soon as a request gets larger, the request does not even hit the server.

I have tried different options for 4-5 hours but could not work it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: As I am using JMeter, I don't know how to see the error. The resulting request row just becomes red in error.

Comment: From the other console client application I have created, I am getting an error: 413 - Request entity too large

Answer (score 1):

JMeter has no limitation .

It's an IIS default limit that you need to change, see:

- [Maximum default POST request size of IIS 7 - how to increase 64kB/65kB limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079397/maximum-default-post-request-size-of-iis-7-how-to-increase-64kb-65kb-limit)

Comment: But till  now I am using the internal Web Server of Visual Studio, as the port number in the URL suggests.

Comment: Even after deploying on IIS, I receive same error - Request entity too large.

Answer (score 0):

Add following inside your `binding` tag

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
```

You binding tag will like this

```
<binding
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
    maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
   <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
</binding>
```