# IIS hangs when POST is 16Kb

Tags: php, iis, php-7, iis-10, php-7.1

I use PHP 7.1 and IIS 10, and I recently encountered a problem when the POST size of a request exceeded 16KB: the request simply hangs forever.

I checked the client and the upload completes, so it's not an upload issue. To be sure, I checked the `post_max_size` variable, and it's 128MB.

When, from IIS, I open the Worker Processes page, I see the request, and its status is ExecuteRequestHandler.

From PHP, the page never gets called, so my guess is that the request hangs while IIS and PHP exchange the POST data.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding the following to your web.config? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15080066/1461181

Comment: It doesn't work. Moreover, the problem is slightly different. Thanks anyway

Comment: Suffering from the same issue. Did you manage to resolve this in any way?